# API Platform with external OpenID provider

Tags: php, symfony, single-sign-on, openid, api-platform.com

I'm dealing with a project where I have a frontend build with React, which connects to an API build with API Platform, and uses an external user provider which implements oauth2 and OpenID protocols (Keycloak).

I think that I can configure API platform as an oauth2 client (through oauth configuration section, but I'm not sure if it will be an oauth client or a server), but I also need to get user information from the OpenID server to store information about the user who has created an entity (the owner).

Is there any way to do that? Or is better to not use API Platform and implement my own API which connects to the OpenID server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you foud a solution ? I have the same question ;)

Comment: Nop, I just didn't use API platform

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is advisable for API Platform to act as a Oauth 2.0 client for external oauth 2.0/OpenId provider in this case, Also It provides a benefit of storing the clientId, clientSecret and other configuration on API platform itself instead of storing on react frontend. Also you can store tokens, expiry, refresh tokens, Other scopes on API platform corresponding to the logged in userId and pass the same to react frontend when required.
For getting userinfo via openId connect, API call will be proxied via API platform to external OpenId provider i.e keycloak.